# Balls in an urn : Can't figure out.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question goes like this:

> An urn contains three red balls, two green balls, and one white ball. Three balls
>   are drawn without replacement from the urn, and the colors are noted in sequence.
>   Find the number of events in the sample space.

Now, if do it manually, I come with $19$ possible events which are:

$$\Omega = \lbrace \space
\color{red}{R R R}, \space
\color{red}{R R} \color{green}G,\space
\color{red}{RR} W,\space 
\color{red}R W \color{green}G,\space 
\color{red}R \color{green}G W,\space 
\color{red}R \color{green}G \color{red}R,\space 
\color{red}R W \color{red}R,\space
\color{red}R\color{green}{GG},\space
\color{green}{G G} \color{red}R,\space 
\color{green}{G G} W,\space 
\color{green}G \color{red}{RR},\space 
\color{green}G\color{red}R W,\space
\color{green}G W \color{red}R,\space 
\color{green}G\color{red}R \color{green}G,\space 
\color{green}G W \color{green}G,\space 
W \color{red}{R R},\space 
W \color{green}{G G},\space 
W \color{red}R \color{green}G,\space 
W \color{green}G \color{red}R \space \rbrace $$

I am trying to figure out if there is any mathematical way to do it?
 I mean without manually listing the sample space?

PS: If I see it in the following way that there are $6$ balls in total, and I need to choose $3$, then I have a total of $^6C_3 = 20$ possibilities. Where is the $1$ extra possibility coming from, or am I missing an event in the sample space?

Comment: 6 choose 3 over counts, as not all of the balls are distinct.

Comment: Over counts will correspond to the case when I can't have identical balls in my sample space. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The problem asks you to **list the sample space**. I'm pretty sure there's no way to do that without **listing the sample space**. You can avoid **manually** listing the sample space, by writing a computer program to make the list. But that's a programming exercise, not a mathematical problem.

Comment: Thanks bof, I meant to state that find the number of events in the sample space. I have edited the question now.

Comment: An event is a subset of the sample space. If $\Omega$ has $19$ elements, there will be $2^19$ events.

Comment: Ok, in simple language : How many ways can we draw 3 balls?

Comment: @joshi I hope you understand why the use of combinations in the form $6C_3$ in this case doesn't work.

Comment: $^6C_3$ has nothing to do with it, because **the order matters**. If the urn contained lots of balls (well, at least three) of every color, the number of possible outcomes would be $3\times3\times3=27$. So you should be asking, how do you account for the $8$ missing outcomes? They are: $3$ whites; $3$ greens; $2$ whites and a red (in $3$ different orders); $2$ whites and a green ($3$ orders). So $1+1+3+3$ outcomes are missing, leaving $27-8=19$.

Comment: I hope you liked my colorful edit. PS- Learning a bit of programming can really help when it comes to these kinds of questions. I recommend Python as a good language for math. (It's not the easiest to start with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The answer is $19$, not $\binom{6}{3}=20.$

Also, I don't think there is such method. But the following way is a bit better.

Let us consider the set of colors as
$$\{rrr\},\{rrg\},\{rrw\}, \{rgg\},\{rgw\},\{ggw\}.$$
Then calculate each number as $1,3,3,3,3!,3.$

Hence, the answer is $1+3+3+3+3!+3=19$.

Comment: Thanks mathlove. This is what I came up with too. Find subset of possible events and compute number of occurrences of each. Nice explanation!

Comment: You are welcome!